# Get data from fetch React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm trying to get data from an Api post with this code

```
componentWillMount() {
      fetch('http://url', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          usuario: 'conosur2',
          password: 'test',
        })

      })
      .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.json());
    })
```

and im getting this on the console

```
Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
```

[image]

i need to access that data, how?, i mean, something like `response.json('clientId')` or `response.json().clientId()`, im noob with react yet, so i dont know how promise works or how fetch works (i came from ajax api consume) *sorry for my english* .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response.json()` returns a promise so you need to resolve it

```
componentWillMount() {
  fetch('http://url', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      usuario: 'conosur2',
      password: 'test',
    })

  })
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json()
  }).then(function(json) {
    console.log('parsed json', json)
  })
```